# First infection of malaria

Tags: human-biology, evolution, malaria, protozoa

As I know *Plasmodium falciperum* survive in either a host animal, human or mosquitoes.

But how does malaria come to **infect either of them** initially?
I am interested in knowing evolution of malaria. How it infected first mosquitoes when neither human nor any other mosquito was infected?

Comment: Could you provide some clarification of your question? Are you wondering how malaria evolved a multi-host life cycle? Or are you more concerned with how malaria is transmitted between a new host-vector cycle?

Comment: @hamilthj i know malaria resides either in mosquitoes or infected bitten animal, question is how it infected first mosquitoes , where did it come from

Comment: Great, I'd suggest clarifying that in your question to highlight your interest in the evolutionary origin of malaria